# Numerals font size to grow from small to big

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a number=12345678, my expect output is first number font size is small then next number font size is bigger than first number and third number font size bigger than second number font size and so on.

How can I archive this using CSS or JS?

Comment: You could use `css`, `js`, or `html`. PHP would just generate whatever you want. Please add code if the question is related to code. As is this is a bit broad.

Comment: First you will have to wrap each digit into an individual HTML element like a span or something, that is the basis for CSS to be able to access them individually to begin with. And then … you apply CSS to those elements to set a font-size. // Please go have a read of [ask]. Mere “how can I” questions are not terribly welcome here, we expect you to at least have some sort of approach to show.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```js
let n='12345678';

box.innerHTML= [...n].map((x,i)=>`<span style='font-size:${2*i+20}px'>${x}</span>`).join('');
```

```html
<div id='box'></div>
```

And pure CSS - but font low quality and number not lie on horizontal line

```css
.num { 
  margin-top:20px;
  transform: translateX(-13px) scaleX(1.35) perspective(100px) rotateY(-45deg);  
  width:100px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-size: 25px;
  /*background: red;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="num">12345678</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is a good solution, worked as charm. Thanks

Comment: @Prabakar I update answer with pure CSS (but not so nice and short like JS)